# removing whitespaces in data.frame R

Tags: r, function, dataframe, removing-whitespace

I have a data.frame

```
test_data <- read.csv("https://stepik.org/media/attachments/course/724/test_data_01.csv", 
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

This data.frame looks like this:

```
 V1      V2       V3      V4       V5
1 -2. 5935    II 2   0.4984 ST 123E -2.154 4
2  -0.2888 ST 123E   1.5636 ST 123E   0.1053
3 -0.828 6 ST 123E -0.9 791  HP 129 -0. 4989
4  -0. 322 ST 123E  -0.3013  HP 129  -0.4032
5  -0.5588 ST 123E   1.2694  HP 129  0.703 9
```

**My goals:**
1) sort only real numeric (V1, V3, V5)

```
num_test<-test_data[sapply(test_data, function(x) grepl("[A-Za-z]", x, perl = T))==F]
```

2) in real numeric(V1, V3, V5) remove whitespaces and then change for V1, V3, V5 factor to numeric

```
str_remove_all(num_test," ")
```

But I don't understand how can I return data.frame with changes. It should look like this:

```
V1      V2      V3      V4      V5
1 -2.5935    II 2  0.4984 ST 123E -2.1544
2 -0.2888 ST 123E  1.5636 ST 123E  0.1053
3 -0.8286 ST 123E -0.9791  HP 129 -0.4989
4 -0.3220 ST 123E -0.3013  HP 129 -0.4032
5 -0.5588 ST 123E  1.2694  HP 129  0.7039
```

Thanks!

Comment: (1) `perl=TRUE` is unnecessary here, you're just slowing it down. (2) `(...) == F` should really be `! (...)` or `isFALSE(...)`. (3) Other than adding `as.numeric` to your whitespace-removal, what part of this doesn't work? Is it just reassigning these values back into the original frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using `str_replace_all`, I'm inferring tidyverse. Try this:

```r
library(dplyr)
test_data %>%
  mutate_at(vars(V1, V3, V5), ~ as.numeric(gsub("\\s", "", .)))
#        V1      V2      V3      V4      V5
# 1 -2.5935    II 2  0.4984 ST 123E -2.1544
# 2 -0.2888 ST 123E  1.5636 ST 123E  0.1053
# 3 -0.8286 ST 123E -0.9791  HP 129 -0.4989
# 4 -0.3220 ST 123E -0.3013  HP 129 -0.4032
# 5 -0.5588 ST 123E  1.2694  HP 129  0.7039
```

since `gsub` works just fine by itself. If you prefer `stringr`, then

```r
library(stringr)
test_data %>%
  mutate_at(vars(V1, V3, V5), ~ as.numeric(str_replace_all(., "\\s", "")))
```

---

**Edit**

To determine which columns have no letter-like data, then

```r
test_data %>%
  mutate_if(~ !any(grepl("[A-Za-z]", .)),
            ~ as.numeric(str_replace_all(., "\\s", "")))
```

Comment: It's a good idea! But I need a function which changes only real numeric. I mean it's columns that doesn't contain any letters. Because of this I wrote this code: 
num_test<-test_data[sapply(test_data, function(x) grepl("[A-Za-z]", x, perl = T))==F]

Comment: But may be dataset where real numeric will be not in columns V1, V3, V5, for example, in V2,V7,V10. In this exercise I should find a way how determine these columns automatically

Comment: Okay, Ekaterina, see my *real* edit (of my answer this time, not your question ... sry about that).